# How to add an image as a text background using CSS pseudo element (:after)

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use a pseudo-element as a background for an HTML text element (h1)?

I know that the simple way of using an image as a text background is using the `background-clip: text;` property directly, but in my case, I need to apply some additional css properties to the background image (rotation and maybe some filter properties as well), and because of this, I cannot apply those css properties directly, as they will be applied to the text element as well.

I think that `:after` pseudo element can do this, but I don't have any success.

Let's say that this is my `h1` wrapped in a div:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>My title that should have an image background</h1>
</div>
```

And this is the css I've tried:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
}

.wrapper h1 { 
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.wrapper h1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: rotate(-3deg); /* the image is required to be rotated */
  background-size: cover;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ztcuv12/

The expected resultL
[image]

Is there a better way of achieving this? Any solutions are welcome.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what effect you want. Is it that the text is to be cut out of the background image but the text is to remain horizontal and the image is rotated or is the text plus its background to be rotated?

Comment: the text should stay horizontal, but only the image will rotate. That's why it needs to be as a separate selector

Answer (score 1):

You can use `backround-image` on wrapper so that if you want to rotate `heading`.
It don't rotate image too.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  /* the image is required to be rotated */
  background-size: cover;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>My title that should have an image background</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but by text background I mean its color .. so not black or other, but an image instead. Something like this: https://codepen.io/Jintos/pen/crlxk